# Implementing regex to find span with class inside javascript file

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I am using regex in python to find `<span class="dlog"...>Whatever you want to put here</span>`, and have been using [pythex](https://pythex.org/?regex=%3Cspan%20class%3D%5C%22dlog%5C%22(.*%3F)%5C%3E(.*%3F)%5C%3C%2Fspan%3E&test_string=%3Cspan%20class%3D%22dlog%22%3Eblah%20blah%3C%2Fspan%3E&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) and crossreferencing [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) to match the case. However, inside of my javascript file, where I am defining a variable containing the regex, as follows:

```
    var tokenRe = /<span class=\"dlog\"(.*?)\>(.*?)\</span>/;
```

I am getting an error: `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /`. Thus, I need help trying to implement this regex inside of my javascript file.

Thanks !

Comment: do you need to escape the slash `\\>`?

Comment: obligatory parsing-html-with-regex-link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 3):

You did not escape the slash for `</span`.  You also don't need so many escapes because of the regex literals:

```
var tokenRe = /<span class="dlog"(.*?)>(.*?)<\/span>/
```